# Plot clickable shapes ontop of an existing au-all.topo.json map

Tags: highcharts, maps, stock

I'd like to plot clickable shapes ontop of an existing au-all.topo.json map

I have a map of Australia, with the state names. I don't want any of that part clickable.

I'd like to create custom shapes (regions), which will scale with the maps, which I can click / roll-over.

Is this possible?

I've looked at the demo for Australia here (https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) which is kind of what I want, but I need none of that to be clickable, and I need to defined my own shapes / polygons which can be interacted with (which when clicked, will populate an html area on the right with details).

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Clickable shape/polygons ontop of an existing map can be achieved in several ways in HighMaps.

1. You can add another series with a point having path.

```js
series: [{
  ...australian map...
}, {
  mapData: [],
  data: [{
    path: 'M 5000 10000 H -1000 V 2000 H 5000'
  }]
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q8n6b2xe/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data.path

2. Another is to use the geometry property to generate a polygon based on the coordinates (lat, lon)

```js
series: [{
  ...australian map...
}, {
  mapData: [],
  data: [{
    geometry: {
      type: 'Polygon',
      coordinates: [
        [
          [120.5859375, -30.6757154],
          [135.0878906, -29.9168522],
          [129.2871094, -18.1458518],
          [120.5859375, -30.6757154]
        ]
      ]
    },
  }]
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qy12ut56/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data.geometry.type

3. There is one more way that is documented and listed in the demo list on the official site. Which consists in using the map from the topo.json file.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/distribution